# flex air excute bat file by NativeProcessStartupInfo

Tags: air, ftp

the bat file's function is downloading file from telnet machine .then i create a air app ,execute the bat file by NativeProcessStartupInfo.
when i execute the air app,it is wireld ,it dose not work,but no errors
if i execute the bat file manually,it works well,why?

```
ftp -i -s:c:\conf 165.11.21.10
```

the conf file is following:
   `user
    pass
    bin
    cd /user
    mget file*
    quit`

Comment: What version of AIR are you using?

Comment: Hi, Please make sure that your AIR apllication is Native App Installer (Eg, Windows should be 'Sample.exe' if it is Mac should be 'Sample.dmg') otherwise you can't access native process.          Also check your Sample-app.xml you need to set <supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>

Comment: thanks,it has been solved after add the code